# unix command to change directory name

Tags: unix

Hi this is a simple question but the solution eludes me at the moment..

I can find out the folder name that I want to change the name of, and I know the command to change the name of a folder is `mv`

so from the current directory if i go

```
ls ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change
```

to which i get the name of the directory is called say `lorem-ipsum-v1-3`

but the directory name may change in the future but it is the only directory in the directory: 
 ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change

how to i programmatically change it to a specific name like `correct-files`

i can do it normally by just doing something like

```
 mv lorem-ipsum-v1-3 correct-files
```

but I want to start automating this so that I don't need to keep copying and pasting the directory name....

any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
find  . -depth -maxdepth 1 -type d | head -n 1 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' correct-files
```

should work fine as long as only one directory should be moved.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about the -I parameter to xargs. -maxdepth on find doesn't exist on all versions of Unix.

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely certain that `relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change` only contains the directory you want to rename, then you can simply use a wildcard:

```
mv ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change/*/ ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change/correct-files
```

This can can also be simplified further, using bash brace expansion, to:

```
mv ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change/{*/,correct-files}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change 
find . -type d -print | while read a ;
do
  mv $a correct-files ;
done
```

Caveats:

- No error handling
- There may be a way of reversing the parameters to mv so you can use xargs instead of a while loop, but that's not standard (as far as I'm aware)
- Not parameterised
- If there any any subdirectories it won't work. The depth parameters on the find command are (again, AFAIK) not standard. They do exist on GNU versions but seem to be missing on Solaris
- Probably others...

Comment: This won't work because `find` will also return the root directory: ~/relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change

Comment: @dogbane You're right. Fixed. Also added another flaw to the list(!).