# rename folder/directory in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

This ia follow up to this question [unix command to change directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341114/unix-command-to-change-directory-name)

but now I want to be able to programmatically change the name of a folder on a windows machine...

any suggestions?

I think `rename` might be useful here but don't quite know how to pipe the name of the folder into it.

Comment: did you try my answer? is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory with an arbirtary name, that's the only directory inside `relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change`, and you want to rename it to `correct-files`, you could use this .CMD batch file:

```
@echo off
Pushd relevant.directory.containing.directory.name.i.want.to.change
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /ad /b') do rename "%%i" correct-files
Popd
```